# Material disappears when applied to part of the object

Tags: materials

When I make the material and I choose a part of the project to give the material to it disappears. [See the video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c_Kgl-mB4VW7Hreeb16d5U5XmFjoxj1X/view?usp=sharing). What is the solution?

Comment: Hi. While videos can be good, ideally all question content should be in the question body, in the form of good descriptions of the issue and images. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like the normals of the faces which have the second and third material applied to them are inverted. There is an option in each material panel which enables Backface Culling. If this is checked then faces with inverted normals will become invisible when viewing those faces from the outside. So check in the **Materials** > **Settings** > **Backface Culling**. If the faces do have inverted normals you can correct them  by selecting the mesh in edit mode and open the **Mesh** menu > **Normals** > **Recalculate Outside**.

Comment: It’s the same problem, but on Blender version 2.8 there is no problem and I don’t understand anything

Comment: I watched your video again and you are correct, there is no reason why faces with the iris and pupil materials should be like that. If you look carefully, when you are in viewport shading solid mode the moment you apply the iris material the shading of the selected faces change and the same thing happens when you apply the pupil material ! And when you switch to material preview mode those faces disappear as if the normals were flipped and you have Backface Culling enabled. A mystery. Perhaps upload the .blend file for others to check. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/help/

Comment: Edit above comment to say : the faces "disappear" while you are still in Solid shading mode even before switching to Material Preview mode.

Comment: @3fingeredfrog I actually shared the file with another person and the material was a very normal work and I don’t know what it is